# Global phone carrier lookup using python

Tags: python-3.x, global, lookup, carrier

I got this code from pypi:

```
from phonenumbers import carrier

ro_number = phonenumbers.parse("+40721234567", "RO")

carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")
```

Output:

```
'Vodafone'
```

I am in India. When I write this code for my phone number it works perfectly and shows Airtel. 
But my project is on finding the carrier of USA phone number
+1xxx xxx xxx.  When I do this for a USA number it returns a null string because mapping is not done.

Please help me to do this for US numbers.

Should I change my laptop location?  I don't know how to do.

Or should I add [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/)?

Please help me.

Comment: Did you look through the examples here: https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers

Comment: from the document: 'For mobile numbers in some countries, you can also find out information about which carrier originally owned a phone number.'

Comment: Added code block, link

Comment: Hi Rick,  the number is showing valid for USA number but it is still returning a null string.

Comment: I have seen the Carrier library too.  Maybe data is less. The code inside the library is like.
          Data= { '4473685': {'en':  'Sky's},   {}, {}, {}......     }                    
Same kind of code for many carrier..  I Can't understand how to add in Library because I don't know how what is 4473685 maybe it is MLS But can't find where to get all the carrier MLS of All USA number so that I could do SMS marketing

Comment: Can anyone tell me lib phonenumbers in python works for us phone numbers or not??

Answer (score 3):

Im a little late to this but I found a solution. phonenumbers does not work for US phone numbers. I have written a little script to get carriers from US phone numbers for free. Here it is:

```py
import requests
import json
def getCarrier(number):
    url = 'https://api.telnyx.com/v1/phone_number/1' + number
    html = requests.get(url).text
    data = json.loads(html)
    carrier = data["carrier"]["name"]
    return carrier
```

All it does is scrape some json from a URL and returns the carrier. Hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: I like it! This is a quick, easy, and _free_ solution. Thank you!

Comment: This no longer works from an api call